# How to create a membership using rules, using membership entity module

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I'm using the [membership entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/membership_entity) module, and the [membership entity commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/membership_entity_commerce) module.

I am trying to create a membership using  rules, without success yet.

There is one membership action available..to activate the membership but thats all.

EDIT:
This is the rule I used for checking out a membership:

```
    { "rules_at_listing_import_create_user_and_membership" : {
    "LABEL" : "At listing import create user and membership",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [
      "rules",
      "commerce_cart",
      "commerce_checkout",
      "membership_entity_commerce",
      "feeds"
    ],
    "ON" : { "feeds_import_listing_import" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "user",
            "param_name" : "[node:field-first-name][node:field-last-name]",
            "param_mail" : [ "node:field-user-email" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "user_created" : "Created user" } }
        }
      },
      { "user_unblock" : { "account" : [ "user-created" ] } },
      { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "user-created" ], "immediate" : "1" } },
      { "commerce_cart_product_add_by_sku" : {
          "USING" : {
            "user" : [ "user-created" ],
            "sku" : "Listingmember-1y",
            "quantity" : "1",
            "combine" : "1"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "product_add_line_item" : { "product_add_line_item" : "Added product line item" } }
        }
      },
      { "commerce_checkout_complete" : { "commerce_order" : [ "product-add-line-item:order" ] } },
      { "membership_entity_commerce_activate_term" : { "commerce_order" : [ "product-add-line-item:order" ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Using this rule, I assume that the membership is created automatically because of the membership product being checked out.

Alternatively, I tried the method without using the membership product, by straight away creating an entity of type membership using rules. That does not work, the membership is not created.

Comment: your rule has to do various save operations, and all this in a single rule. Unexpected things may happen (or not happen). At this point I'd enable Rules debugging (within "settings"), to see if any errors show up there. If you do, please add relevant rules logging info (shown near the top of the page) as an extra update to your question.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens No errors appear in the rules log or dblog. The ruls log shows: https://i.imgur.com/eAGCEfm.png   (I did not expand the default commerce reactions).. Basically it doesn't show much info about a membership

Answer (score 0):

I did a good comparison of the Commerce membership entity module and the Commerce Licenses module, and the commerce licences can do te same, and has a lot more extra features, is more flexible. So switching to that module was my solution.